# What were the first music awards given and when did music awards start to gain visibility?

Tags: history, award

I wonder what were the first music awards given, and around when music awards started to gain visibility?

Comment: Are we talking about formal, nation-wide awards?  US-centric or otherwise?  I'm imagining some little town in the Ukraine having a folk song competition with rewards back in the 1700s.

Comment: Please specify the location! Without that a answer would be useless, as it could apply to any country, town or area.  Thank You :)

Comment: Nation-wide award. Any country.

Comment: Within the frame of a competition (like Eurovision) or outside (like Grammy)? Music competitions were held since the dawn of history e.g. Pythian games in 6th century BCE. Most probably there were even earlier musical contests.

Comment: This question should be closed because it is too broad as written. It would likely become a list type question, which is off-topic. [***Are list questions on-topic?***](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/77/are-list-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Through admittedly scattershot searching, here's a small chronology of awards. The idea of making a complete list doesn't appeal. I suspect there were classical music awards or prizes earlier than this but that's not my specialty.

The Edison awards website says that it is one of the oldest, so this may be about right for commercial music awards.

- 1943: [Pulitzer Prize for music](http://www.pulitzer.org/bycat/Music)
- 1956: [Eurovision award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eurovision_Song_Contest_winners)
- 1959: [Grammy awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Annual_Grammy_Awards)
- 1960: [Edison Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_Award) (Netherlands)
- 1977: [Brit awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_Awards)